# c# application not opening when trying to execute it

Tags: c#

My friend showed me on his pc, how to execute code, without using visual studio. He opened the file location of the project -> bin -> Debug -> netcoreapp3.1. Then he copied the application file and pasted it on his Desktop. Then he double-clicked it and the application opened. I was really impressed. I tried to do the same, but it wasn't working... and I have no idea why. Here is the video of me trying to do exactly what he did:

video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xejkdqwwScs

Comment: Well you're copying *one file* when the application clearly consists of more than that. If your friend's app worked that way, I suspect they were building it in a different way or targeting a different framework. In general I'd recommend against doing this though - publish the application (to create a complete set of files) and keep those files together... create a *shortcut* on your desktop if you want.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to execute a C# application, it is likely that you need to ensure that the necessary DLLs are in the same directory as the application executable. DLLs are libraries of code that the application needs in order to run properly. Without the appropriate DLLs, the application may not run or may not run correctly. To make sure the necessary DLLs are in the same directory as the application. Once you have identified the necessary DLLs, you can copy them into the same directory as the application executable. This should allow the application to run correctly.